# App Engine Flex environment with GRPC and Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, grpc

I am using gRPC on Google Cloud GKE environment. Given this URL "https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/" it implies that we can use gRPC with App Engine Flexible environment. However from the documentation it is impossible to find in how we can use ESP with the App Engine flexible runtime. I've tried it, but I cannot see how to expose both my health checks and expose the gRPC ports through to ESP given my App Engine URL. I based my tests on this:

[image]

Where is the documentation so I can use gRPC, with ESP (Extensible service proxy, nginx based) on this environment? Is the documentation wrong or is my assumption that I can use Firebase JWT Auth like I do on GKE? I prefer to use App Engine Flexible for my server. I use iOS as a mobile client, fully locked in to Google/Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

That was mistake in the documentation. gRPC with App Engine flex is not supported. The documentation has been updated. Sorry for the confusion.